# moving between tiles in a tile map

Tags: java, swing

i currently have a tile map and i only display a certain part of the map on the screen with the user in the middle, however i can't make it so that the character moves freely between tiles as opposed to tile to tile.

```
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { 
super.paintComponent(g); //required to ensure the panel si correctly redrawn
for(int i = 0; i <visibleHeight;i=i+1){ 
  for(int j = 0; j <visibleHeight;j=j+1){
    g.setColor(backgroundColor);
    g.fillRect(j*boxWidth, i*boxHeight, boxWidth, boxHeight);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawRect(j*boxWidth, i*boxHeight, boxWidth, boxHeight);
    g.fillRect(j*boxWidth, i*boxHeight, boxWidth, boxHeight);

    if ((hero.getY()-visibleHeight/2+i) < world.length && (hero.getX()-visibleHeight/2+j) >= 0      // check if the desired
          && (hero.getY()-visibleHeight/2+i) >= 0 && (hero.getX()-visibleHeight/2+j) < world.length){// location to draw is within bounds
      // draw the map according to the player location
      if (world[hero.getY()-visibleHeight/2+i][hero.getX()-visibleHeight/2+j] == 1){ // subtract visibleHeight/2+i 
        g.drawImage(tree,j*boxWidth, i*boxHeight, boxWidth, boxHeight, this);        //to get all boxes from half 
      }else if(world[hero.getY()-visibleHeight/2+i][hero.getX()-visibleHeight/2+j] == 2){ // the visible height under 
        g.setColor(trailColor);                                                           // and half the visible height above the player
        g.fillRect(j*boxWidth, i*boxHeight, boxWidth, boxHeight);
      }else{
        g.setColor(backgroundColor);
        g.fillRect(j*boxWidth, i*boxHeight, boxWidth, boxHeight);
      }
    }
  }
}
clock.update();
frameRate.update();
hero.update(clock, world); // update hero
hero.draw(g); // update hero
//update the content
frameRate.draw(g,10,10);
//draw the framerate

//request a repaint
repaint();
```

}

```
  public void draw(Graphics g) { 
g.setColor(Color.BLUE); //There are many graphics commands that Java can use
g.fillRect(512, 512, this.width, this.length);
g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 20));
g.setColor(Color.black);
g.drawString(this.x + ":" + this.y, 200, 400);
```

}

```
  public void update(Clock clock, int[][] world){
//boxWidth*world.length is equal to the total size of the map converted to pixels
if (this.x + xShift*clock.getElapsedTime()*((GamePanel.boxWidth*world.length)/1024) > 0 
      && (this.x + xShift*clock.getElapsedTime()*(GamePanel.boxWidth*world.length)/1024) < GamePanel.boxWidth*world.length){
  // multiply by (GamePanel.boxWidth*world.length)/1024) to make it so you move the same number of blocks regardless of the visible height
  this.x += xShift*clock.getElapsedTime()*((GamePanel.boxWidth*world.length)/1024);

}if (this.y + yShift*clock.getElapsedTime()*((GamePanel.boxWidth*world.length)/1024) > 0 
       && (this.y + yShift*clock.getElapsedTime()*(GamePanel.boxWidth*world.length)/1024) < GamePanel.boxWidth*world.length){
  // multiply by (GamePanel.boxWidth*world.length)/1024) to make it so you move the same number of blocks regardless of the visible height
  this.y += yShift*clock.getElapsedTime()*((GamePanel.boxWidth*world.length)/1024);
}
```

}